# How to limit progress circle to full in 60 instead of 100%

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, angular2-material

In my angular 2 project I'm using angular 2 material design to display progress i used progress circle like this, actually I'm using it as time out and and i want to limit to 60 second, like when 60 arrive the whole progress should be full

```
<md-progress-circle mode="determinate" [value]="clock | async"
></md-progress-circle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the "value" property of  only accepts a percentage value, a solution would be to convert to convert **clock** (which I understood can take values from 0 to 60) into a percentage.

You could achieve this conversion like this:

```
<md-progress-circle mode="determinate" [value]="(clock * 100 / 60) | async"></md-progress-circle>
```

Comment: I have edited my question, please see the updated question

Comment: @blackHawk I saw you changed the title, but I think my answer still answers your question. Did you try it out?

Comment: yeah, actually clock is observable, and it cant be changed into percentage, so by doing the progress circle vanished

Comment: Please give me the code for your clock from the Angular2 component.

Comment: I see you no longer have the `async` pipe in the Plunker, which allows the clock number [0-60] to be converted into a percentage: http://plnkr.co/edit/o84zNU06OMGnCXHVoFXf?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it also works with `map()` and the `async` pipe: http://plnkr.co/edit/cbkomi?p=preview. I removed the md-progress-circle tag since the Plunker does not have the necessary imports to display it.

Comment: Yes did you test at your side? Because it was working fine yesterday but since night it totally broke, progress circle doesn't full at 60

Comment: Do you mean if I tested with an actual progress circle? No, because I do not have that module installed. Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: No error just progress circle dnt fill whole when 60 reaches,

Comment: It reaches 60 of 100 and the stop filling, i want when it reaches 60 the whole circle should be filed

Comment: This is weird, because in the Plunkers I sent you the clock value goes all the way up to 100.

Comment: I think i'm making it confusing, i see if i send image whats going on and what i want

Comment: Ummm what about if i say, the max-value of circle should be 60 instead of 100?

Comment: Its like when value reaches 60 the whole circle filled, as if it did when value reaches 100